# (Php and HTML) How to not run code when including text from a .txt file

Tags: php, html

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="major last">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </header>
    <form method="post" action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                <input type="text" name="Date" placeholder="Meeting Date (mm/dd/yy)" />
            </div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                <input type="text" name="Topic" placeholder="Meeting Topic" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <textarea name="Summary" placeholder="Summary of the Meeting" rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div>
        <p><?php echo file_get_contents( "data.txt" ); ?></p>
    </div>
</body>`
```

Php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Date']) && isset($_POST['Topic']) && isset($_POST['Summary'])) {
    $data = 'Date: ' . ' ' . $_POST['Date'] . ' Topic: ' . $_POST['Topic'] . ' Summary: ' . $_POST['Summary'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

I am trying to eventually make a form that will take information and record it in a text file. That text file will eventually be included in a web page. Currently, however, if code (such as `<a href="websiteaddress">websitename</a>`) is typed into the form, then when it is included, that code is executed. How can I edit my code to take the response as a string, rather than plain text?

Comment: Please paste your code here, not on Pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the htmlspecialchars() function in PHP. For example:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlspecialchars('<a href="websiteaddress">websitename</a>');
echo "<pre>";
```

Obviously, once you write the code to read from the code from your text file, you will extract one or more lines and place the variable in htmlspecialchars() function.

One word of caution: be very careful about someone putting sinister code into your form such as JavaScript code. Look into XSS and other similar attacks. Since you are using htmlspecialchars() this should take care of most of those attacks, but just be careful how you implement your code.

Comment: @kowjow7 Would you have to specify each possible code or.. how would that be implemented?

Comment: @Goman693, no you could include a whole block of code or your entire text file if you want.

Comment: @kowjow7 I've done a bit more research, htmlspecialchars() wouldn't work for what I'm trying to do, since it's going to be updated automatically and I cant copy the new text file into the (), but I did find something about escaping. How could I escape this properly so code isn't run?

Comment: @Goman693 How is it going to be updated automatically? And what is going to be updated? The text file?

Comment: At the end of meetings, a historian will enter the Date, Topic, and a Summary of the meeting, and all of that information will be stored in the textfile and then on a webpage, that textfile will be included and the Date, Topic, and Summary will be shown. @kojow7

Comment: Your code shouldn't have to change when the text file changes. Try implementing the file reader code and you'll see what I mean. You currently have code to display a form, process the form and save the data to the text file. Your code PHP code that reads the text file is where your htmlspecialchars should go.